# How can i catch an error or use "try and catch" after verifying there's a missing element on Katalon with Groovy

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I am trying to figure out how to catch an error after verifying there is a missing element. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m36MU.jpg)

WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Page_SIUC inCommonComodo CSR SubmissionC-S-_d712f4/body_hrcenterh2uThis service requires that _314279'), 
    0)

The above code is what I use to verify that an element is there.

Answer (score 0):

`WebUI.verifyElementPresent()` will return a boolean value. That means you can do something like this (**note** the logical negation "!" before the method):

```
if(!WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Page_SIUC inCommonComodo CSR SubmissionC-S-_d712f4/body_hrcenterh2uThis service requires that _314279'), 1){
    WebUI.comment("Element not found!")
}
```